# How to diplay array in express ejs template

Tags: arrays, express, ejs

I am trying to show a json file isnide my express ejs template for that my json file looks like this :

[Data File](https://gist.github.com/nwoow/be90827a121e53bef12a6ba9a882d190)

For that my ejs file is like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
<h1><% var a = title %></h1>
    <%for (var result in a){%>
           <li><%=result%></li>
   <%}%>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I sm using this code:`<%=result%>`

I am getting this result :
error
Books

I am trying t show all the data of books in my view file for that I am trying this code `<%=result[0]%>`but I am getting this value

.e
   .B

I am trying to access Books Id or other detail how can I show it here in this view file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should go and read some docs [EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/getting_started.html)

here you can see the for loop example and for your solution the answer is very simple you need to use this code and you are done:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>

<h1><% var a = title %></h1>
<% var z = a["Books"] %>
   <% for(var i=0; i<z.length; i++) { %>
           <li>
          <%= z[i].Tweet %>
           </li>
       <% } %>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `forEach`:

```
  <body>
   <ul>
       <% books.forEach(function(book){ %>
         <li><%- book.id %></li>
       <%});%>
   </ul>
  </body>
```